# Minecraft: question about loot tables

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I want to make datapack that changes amount of items dropped from mined blocks and killed mobs by player, in range from 1 to 1024 for example, how can it be done?
I know how to change dropped items to a specific amount and not range for one block, how can I make it for range and make it for all blocks and mobs?
Basically this is something like in this video:

Comment: The wiki is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the **min** and **max** properties. Here is an example of a loot table that drops 1-1024 diamonds:

```
{
    "pools": [
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "minecraft:diamond",
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "minecraft:set_count",
                            "count": {
                                "min": 1,
                                "max": 1024
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Since there is no way to apply a single loot table to all blocks and mobs, you need to create a loot table like this for every block and mob.